# Insert current datetime into mysql table resulting an error

Tags: mysql

I am creating a procedure called `AccLikesVid` inserting into a table named `a_likes_v` ([table infomation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHtKa.png)):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE AccLikesVid(username VARCHAR(30), vidid INT(11), type BOOL)
BEGIN
    IF (type = 1) THEN
        INSERT INTO a_likes_v VALUES (username, vidid, NOW(), 1);
    ENDIF;     
END$$
```

But when I execute the above code, MySQL Workbench generates an error: ***Error Code 1193. Unknown system variable 'now'***

Could you tell me what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE AccLikesVid(username VARCHAR(30), vidid INT(11), v_type BOOL)
BEGIN
    IF (v_type = 1) THEN  -- TYPE is keyword, avoid such identifiers
        INSERT INTO a_likes_v(account_name, video_id, dtime, liked) 
        VALUES (username, vidid, NOW(), 1);  -- avoid blind insert
    END IF;   -- END IF not ENDIF
END$$
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=02abfda67d02028fd916aeaf59da06ab)**